# webservice not returning a array

Tags: php, arrays, web-services, soap

I need help with this webservice, it is returning this `stdClass Object ( [GETOfertasAereasResult] => )`

I need to return an array with all the values.

```
<?php   
    try {
        $wsdl_url = 'http://portaldoagente.com.br/wsonlinetravel/funcoes.asmx?WSDL';
        $client = new SOAPClient($wsdl_url);
        $params = array(
            'sLojaChave' => "Y2Y4ZGRkOWU=",
        );
        $return = $client->GETOfertasAereas($params);
        print_r($return);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Exception occured: " . $e;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Where's the documentation of the web-service ?

Comment: http://portaldoagente.com.br/wsonlinetravel/funcoes.asmx

Comment: You don't POST an XML in your request: http://portaldoagente.com.br/wsonlinetravel/funcoes.asmx?op=GETOfertasAereas

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is like the following:

```
$return = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org    /2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap12:Body>
<GETOfertasAereasResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
     <GETOfertasAereasResult>Some result content</GETOfertasAereasResult>
</GETOfertasAereasResponse>
</soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>';
```

Try this:

```
$obj = new SimpleXMLElement($return);
$body = $obj->children('soap12', true)->Body->children();
$content = (string) $body->GETOfertasAereasResponse->GETOfertasAereasResult;
var_dump($content);
```

Comment: It is still not working, i'm getting this message scrip stdClass Object ( [GETOfertasAereasResult] => ) string(0) ""  I want to get the returned data as a array. when i test the wsdl i get a result big result with a lot of data.

Comment: @user2295500 - I don't know what your data looks like. The code I posted works with the data I posted. If you have something different, please post it.

Comment: @user2295500 I not a good php programmer, i need to get the data that comes back from the xml and show it in html. I think is to parse the data right?

Comment: The data that i want to get is the what is comming from the webservice, when i send the 'sLojaChave' it is supposed to come back with a lot of data.

Comment: @user2295500 - I can't write code for soem unknown chunk of XML. Without any data, I can't help.